# Key issue with EF Model linking to CRM Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a simple model in MVC4 that links two CRM Product entities together. The CRM entities are early bound classes generated by CrmSvcUtil.exe and the model is:

```
namespace Demo.Models
{
  public class ProductLink
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("ProductSource")]
      [Display(Name = "Product Source")]
      public Guid? SourceId { get; set; }
      public virtual Xrm.Product ProductSource { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("ProductTarget")]
      [Display(Name = "Product Target")]
      public Guid? TargetId { get; set; }
      public virtual Xrm.Product ProductTarget { get; set; }
  }
}
```

when I try and add the controller I get:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Demo.Models.ProductLink'. One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> - System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'RelatedEntityCollection' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
> - System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'EntityCollection' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
> - System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Relationship' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
> - System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : EntityType: EntitySet 'RelatedEntityCollections' is based on type 'RelatedEntityCollection' that has no keys defined.
> - System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : EntityType: EntitySet 'EntityCollections' is based on type 'EntityCollection' that has no keys defined.
> - System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : EntityType: EntitySet 'Relationships' is based on type 'Relationship' that has no keys defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work. The early-bound entities generated by CrmSvcUtil.exe are not written in such a way that they'll work with EF code-first.

You'll need to write your own early-bound entities to make this work. You can do that either manually or through a [custom code generation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547384.aspx) for CrmSvcUtil.exe.

An alternative approach is to write a manually code EF code-first compatible classes for the the entities you need and then write a mapper from them to the CrmSvcUtil early-bound classes.

Comment: What needs to be added to the early-bound entities to make them work with EF?

Comment: Well I'm no EF expert but at a minimum everything needs a primary key defined either by code, code attributes, or convention. The underlying `Entity`, which is inherited by the code generated by CrmSvcUtil.exe, was not designed for EF Code-First usage.

Comment: The proper way to handle this requirement is to create your EF Code First compliant POCO and then map between the `Entity`-based classes from CrmSvcUtil.exe and your POCOs. You can look at AutoMapper as one possible way to automate these mappings.